# Python store current line in iterable file object

Tags: python, file, while-loop, iterable

How do I store the current line of an iterable file? Apparently Python doesn't support inline assignment

```
f = open('parseMe.txt', 'r')

iroFile = iter(f)

while("\\" in (curLine = next(iroFile))):
    print curLine
```

I tried the following even: but I still get syntax errors.

```
while((curLine = next(iroFile)):
   if ("\\" in curLine):
      print curLine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a brace in

```
while((curLine = next(iroFile)):
```

also the outermost braces aren't necesary.

This code should do the same

```
print "".join([x for x in open("x.txt") if '\\' in x])
```

or

```
import sys
[sys.stdout.write(x) for x in open("x.txt") if '\\' in x]
```

or

```
import sys
if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    from __future__ import print_function
[print(x) for x in open("x.txt") if '\\' in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, assignment is a statement, not an expression - but if you get used to Python idioms, I doubt you'll miss it.

Here's something along the lines of what you appear to be looking for:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python

with open('parseMe.txt', 'r') as file_:
    for curLine in file_:
        if '\\' not in curLine:
            break
        print curLine.rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

File is iterable, so you should use a `for` loop:

```
f = open('parseMe.txt', 'r')
for line in f:
    if '\\' in line:
        print line
```

Answer (score 0):

Python `file` objects can be iterated over line by line, so this is the simplest way:

```
for curLine in open('parseMe.txt', 'r'):
    if "\\" in curLine:
        print curLine
```